# Spanning radiogroup in two cells

Tags: android, radio-group

I have a 
    `<RadioGroup android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_span="2">`

with two
    `<RadioButtons>`

I need to span in a
    `<TableRow>`

But only the first button shows.

The snippet is here:
http://pastebin.com/GLVugZWb

Any hints ?

Answer (score 0):

You should set android:layout_width, _height and _weight for radio buttons. Set _weight parameter = 1. Hope this help.